# NSMutable array - "Not an objective-C object" error

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I am not totally sure why it is that it is returning the error "not an objective-C object" at the commented line. Any help would be appreciated.

Additionally, I am very new to objective-C, and I do realize there is a high possibility this is a very silly mistake. However any advice will help.

```
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorBrain()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *operandStack;
@end

@implementation CalculatorBrain

@synthesize operandStack = _operandStack;

- (NSMutableArray *)operandStack
{
    if(!_operandStack){
    _operandStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }// end if
    return _operandStack;
}//end operandStack

- (void)pushOperand:(double)operand
{
    NSNumber *operandObject = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand];
    [self.operandStack addObject:operandObject];
}//end pushOperand

- (double)popOperand
{
    NSNumber *operandObject = [self.operandStack lastObject];//error "Not an objective-c object"
    if(operandObject) [self.operandStack removeLastObject];
    return [operandObject doubleValue];
}//end popOperand

- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation
{
    double result = 0;

    if([operation isEqualToString:@"+"]){
    result = [self popOperand] + [self popOperand];
} else if([operation isEqualToString:@"-"]){
    double subtrahend = [self popOperand];
    result = [self popOperand] - subtrahend;
} else if([operation isEqualToString:@"*"]){
    result = [self popOperand] * [self popOperand];
} else if([operation isEqualToString:@"/"]){
    double divisor = [self popOperand];
    if(divisor) result = [self popOperand] / divisor;
}//end if
[self pushOperand:result];
return result;

}//performOperation

@end
```

Comment: You are crashing there? Is that all of the error message? Can you set a breakpoint right below that line and then, in the console, type po [self.operandStack lastObject] Or maybe look to the left of the console for information about self then operandStack and its contents. But really, they all have to be objective c objects to be contained in an array.

Comment: Is it possible that anywhere else something is setting operandStack to something other than an NSMutableArray? (i.e. your check for nil is failing, but it's not an object).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be caused by the the incorrect operation order in the function popOperand. See my comments inline, the last line return [operandObject doubleValue] accessed a already released object. After running this code several time, it might cause memory problem and in turn, you might see the error at your comment line.

```
- (double)popOperand
{
    NSNumber *operandObject = [self.operandStack lastObject];
    if(operandObject) [self.operandStack removeLastObject];
    // When you remove the lastObject(operandObject) from the Array, the operandObject retainCount is zero.
    // Here, the operandObject is deallocated and should not be used.
    // But you call it after it was released.
    return [operandObject doubleValue];
}//end popOperand
```

This might be OK, when you only call popOperand once or several times. But this will result memory error. I guess the error doesn't occur every time when the popOperand is called. Here is my solution.

```
- (double)popOperand
{
    double result = 0.0;
    NSNumber *operandObject = [self.operandStack lastObject];
    if(operandObject) 
    {
        result = [operandObject doubleValue];
        [self.operandStack removeLastObject];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Local (pointer) variables are "strong" while they remain in scope; if I understand correctly. The only place your risk is actual is when assigning to a weak property.

Comment: You're correct. Local variables does be "strong", but it requires the local pointer variable points to a local created object. The pointer variable has two part, the variable itself and the object it points to. The pointer variable is always local as it was defined as NSNumber* operandObject; But the object it points to is not always "local". In this case, `NSNumber* operandObject = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand];` You can say both variable and object are local in some sort. (Actually, the object belongs to the auto release pool from ownership view). Because you create it in the scope.

Comment: But in the case `NSNumber* operandObject = [operandStack lastObject]`, the operandObject is local but the object it points to is not local. The object was created and added to the array in pushOperand, it belongs to the array operandStack. If it was removed from the array, it will be released (in this case, only array owns the object after pushOperand). Therefore the return [operandObject doubleValue] is calling a already released object. This behavior is very dangerous. Any object will be released if its retainCount equals to 0.

Comment: Local variables are only "stong" under ARC and, under ARC, it doesn't matter if the object is created in the local scope or retrieved from the array.   If the OP's code is non-ARC, then the removeLastObject is the problem, but much of the commentary above is just wrong.   Note that absolute retain counts are a useless consideration.