# how safe is it to mix ARC and non-ARC code in the same iOS project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm modifying an [open source app](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) that is non-ARC. Most of my iOS experience is with ARC enabled objective-c, so when I create and add new files to the project I tend to make them ARC compliant using [compiler flags](http://korutech.hubpages.com/hub/Adding-non-ARC-sources-to-ARC-projects) (especially when i'm faced with weird non-arc code [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11788000/766570)).

The thing that keeps me up at night is the question: how safe and reliable is it to mix arc and non-arc code in my project? When QA time comes will it be a nightmare to test for things like memory leaks and performance etc etc? Asked another way.. is it worth converting the existing non-arc code to arc code and get rid of the potential trouble?

Comment: Those are compiler flags, not linker flags. Also, using ARC doesn't absolve you of needing to test your app for leaks and performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can mix freely without any problems.

Comment: Yes, indeed this is all the answer that you need.  There is one caveat (something about precompiled code with poor naming conventions tricking ARC into overreleasing) but that I don't think that applies in this situation.

Comment: err.. well i greatly respect both of you and I acknowledge both of your technical experience.. I was hoping for some evidence or documentation? or are your answers simply based on personal experience (which still could be enough in itself)

Comment: @abbood - ARC is not magic, it simply looks through your code at compile time and adds the necessary retains and releases. The generated code is no different than the code that you would have written yourself. From the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226):"You can also choose to use ARC on a per-file basis if it’s more convenient for you to use manual reference counting for some files."

Comment: Can you explain the purpose/need for the `-fno-objc-arc` compile flag? I'm using a pre-arc library that says to add this flag for each of its source files.

Comment: Did you mean that it's safe as long as you use the proper flags? Because it certainly isn't compiling without them.

Comment: It is safe, but you have to use the flags for it to compile.

Comment: The -fno-objc-arc flag is needed to compile code that doesn't use ARC. With ARC turned on, retain/release/autorelease are illegal. If you compile code that isn't written for ARC and contains these calls, you must turn off ARC for that file. Make sure to use the static analyser to find any problems - the static analyser basically finds out what retain/release calls ARC would have done, which ones the code does, and compares.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's safe since some code is forbidden when ARC is turned on such as this method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

And of course when releasing:

```
[exampleVariable release];
```

Which can be present in the non-ARC projects.

Comment: my question is assuming that all such non-safe code has already been accounted for (ie taken out)

Comment: Well in that case, it is completely safe since that is the only thing that matters.

Comment: Wouldn't accounting for the non-ARC code essentially make it ARC code?